# Viewing expired reflog logs

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reflog, reflog

Is there any way to view expired reflogs? I've been keeping a few local commit I made months ago on a local branch and I've kept it up to date with our remote branch by rebasing frequently. Somehow I've lost all of my local commits for this branch and have no way to recover it since git reflog is not showing logs past a certain date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the reflogs are expired, they are removed from the reflog.  So you would not see them in the reflog, as is by design.

See [`man git-reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: So I guess I lost my local commits forever :(

Answer (score 1):

The "expire" subcommand prunes older reflog entries. Entries older than expire time, or entries older than expire-unreachable time and not reachable from the current tip, are removed from the reflog. This is typically not used directly by end users.